# Как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

На сайтах виднеются плашечки с предложением зарегистрироваться или войти в систему через различные социальные сети. И стало интересно, как же правильно должно быть: "Войдите в систему через..." и дальше перечисление названий соц. сетей или "Авторизуйтесь через..." и дальше перечисление названий соц. сетей?

Comment: "Правильно" с точки зрения русского языка. Смотрела большой толковый словарь, там написано, что есть слово "авторизовать", но не "авторизировать". Видимо, кто ответил на вопрос, сам не в курсе, как же правильно пишется это слово

Comment: Ну это скорее задающий не знает, о чем бы ещё таком спросить.
Вы интересовались альтернативой "войти" или "авторизоваться". На что и получили ответ. Не говоря уж о том, что есть понятие профессионального сленга, с которым "отвечающий", будучи программистом с без малого соракалетним стажем, знаком не понаслышке.
 
Насчет "авторизировать" или "авторизовать". В словарях нет ни того, ни другого. То, что вы увидели у Кузнецова, не имеет ни малейшего отношения к рассматриваемому значению. "Авторизировать" - компьютерный неологизм, фонетическая калька с английского.

Comment: Да, вопрос был именно в том, как правильно говорить. Как в русском языке будет корректно звучать фраза, приглашающая зарегистрированного пользователя войти на сайт. 
Вопрос, на мой взгляд, простой. Опрашивая знакомых филологов, получила разные ответы, потому и решила спросить здесь.
На том же сайте грамота.ру написано: "авторизуйтесь". Потому и возникло недопонимание, откуда "авторизируйтесь" могло взяться? Автора ответа благодарю за ответ и комментарий, причем именно комментарий помог разобраться в ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Ну это зависит от того, с какой точки зрения "правильно".
Русскому языку ни то, ни другое не противоречит.
Технически "авторизируйтесь", наврное, точнее. Но, с другой стороны, "вход в систему" вполне понятно и общепринято, "авторизация" в этом смысле менее очевидно.